# Перебор объектов массива (цикл for, while)

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты

Учебное задание. Пытаюсь перебрать массив объектов.

```
let studentsArray = [
  { name: "student1", grade: 93 },
  { name: "student2", grade: 53 },
  { name: "student3", grade: 40 },
];
```

Задача- нужно написать функцию, которая будет перебирать этот массив, и приписывать каждому объекту ключ с буквой, соответсвующей оценке студента

```
    (0-50 = F
    51-60 = E
    61-70 = D
    71-80 = C
    81-100 = A)
```

То есть должно получиться так-

```
      { name: "student1", grade: 93, final: A},
      { name: "student2", grade: 53, final: E},
      { name: "student3", grade: 40, final: F},
```

Но мой код ниже выдает undefined, и починить его я так и не смог.

```
let studentsArray = [
  { name: "student1", grade: 91 },
  { name: "student2", grade: 51 },
  { name: "student3", grade: 45 },
];

function checkStudentGrade() {
  for (let i = 0; i < studentsArray.length; i++) {
    if (studentsArray[i].grade < 0 ||typeof studentsArray[i].grade !== "number"
    ) {studentsArray[i].final = "Error!";
    } else if (studentsArray[i].grade >= 0 && studentsArray[i].grade <= 50) {
      studentsArray[i].final = "F";
    } else if (studentsArray[i].grade > 50 && studentsArray[i].grade <= 60) {
      studentsArray[i].final = "E";
    } else if (studentsArray[i].grade > 60 && studentsArray[i].grade <= 70) {
      studentsArray[i].final = "D";
    } else if (studentsArray[i].grade > 70 && studentsArray[i].grade <= 80) {
      studentsArray[i].final = "C";
    } else if (studentsArray[i].grade > 80 && studentsArray[i].grade <= 100) {
      studentsArray[i].final = "A";
    } else {
      studentsArray[i].final = "The number is too high!";
    }
  }
}
console.log(checkStudentGrade(studentsArray));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, для улучшения отладки и читаемости лучше вынести в отдельную функцию определение оценки:

```
function getFinal(grade){
  if ( 0 <= grade && grade < 51) return 'F';
    if (51 <= grade && grade < 61) return 'E';
    if (61 <= grade && grade < 71) return 'D';
    if (71 <= grade && grade < 81) return 'C';
    else return 'A';
}
```

Далее с помощью функции `forEach` проблегаемся по всем элементам и выставляем оценки:

```
studentsArray.forEach(function (o) {
  o.final = getFinal(o.grade);
});
```

Результат:

```
0: Object { name: "student1", grade: 91, final: "A" }​
1: Object { name: "student2", grade: 51, final: "E" }​
2: Object { name: "student3", grade: 45, final: "F" }
```

По поводу вашей ошибки, то дело в том, что ваша функция ничего не возваращет, поэтому в console.log возвращает она undefined, просто отработав. А выводить в консоль вам нужно сам объект `studentsArray`
`console.log(studentsArray)`.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо! А мои потуги есть возможность поправить или это просто неправильный код сам по себе?

Comment: @VladimirAkimov, Я ведь внизу написал в чём проблема и что делать. Сначала вызывайте функцию, а потом в `console.log` выводите объект `studentsArray`.